# Is it possible to use only 2 CPU cores using docker build command?

Tags: docker, build, concurrency, cpu, docker-build

I'm using `docker build -t my-image .` on a VM with 4 CPU cores.

I would like to use only 2 of them to build the image, because during the build all four cores go to 100%.

Is it possible?

Comment: Do you know what specific step is using all of the processing power, and can you limit that?

Comment: No I don't know...

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the VM is based on a linux distribution, so the solution should be:

```bash
taskset --cpu-list 0,1 docker build -t my-image .
```

Comment: I'd guess this won't work because `docker build` just makes an API request to the Docker daemon.  So this would limit the `docker build` process to two specific cores, but it's not the thing doing the work.

Comment: You are right. In such case, by the same command, you can find the Daemon PID and give it the affinity you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the concurrency in buildx which can be a poor substitute for limiting the CPU utilization:

```bash
$ cat buildkitd.toml
[worker.oci]
  max-parallelism = 2

$ docker buildx create --config buildkitd.toml --driver docker-container --use limited
```

This would applies to builds performed with `docker buildx build`. Note that if individual steps use multiple CPUs, then this will not stop those steps from using all of the CPU, which is why I consider this a poor substitute.

If you were to use the kubernetes driver, there is a `limits.cpu=2` which should work better.

Since docker is using `/docker/buildx` as the parent cgroup for all buildx containers by default, you could attempt to set the limit there. However that change will vary based on your cgroup version, and won't be a good option if you are in Docker Desktop since that uses an embedded VM.

If you are in Docker Desktop, you can limit the CPU usage of the entire embedded VM from the Docker Desktop settings. That will also limit any running containers, not just builds.

Reference:

- `buildx create`: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/buildx_create/
- `buildkitd.toml`: https://github.com/moby/buildkit/blob/master/docs/buildkitd.toml.md